# Dump BigQuery select statement results into Google Cloud SQL database table

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql

How to dump BigQuery select statement results into Google Cloud SQL database. The only way I am aware of is dumping the results to Google Cloud Storage and then Cloud SQL can read from it. 
Is there a better way to implement this? I want this to happen everyday.

Comment: how big will be the data?

Comment: around 5000 rows per query and 10-15 such queries.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a cron job that will use the BigQuery API to query the data and the MySQL API to post the data.

You can use the [Cloud DataFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) that will use BigQuery query as input, but you will need to write a custom sink ([Java](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io-java), [Python](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/custom-io-python)) (or find one) that will dump it to MySql.

Comment: Is there a documentation for writing SQL based custom sinks?

Comment: @Prabhjot not that I'm aware of but I added links to the answer on the custom sinks